# Internet Explorer allow transition in a false contenteditable div element

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

Internet Explorer allows a transition in a contenteditable="false" div element.

In other browsers everything works fine, the transition does not occur, but not in IE.

CSS

```
#sch-brand-filter {
  width:100px; 
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px white solid;
}

#sch-brand-filter:focus {
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0.125em #ffd151;
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow .2s ease-out;
            transition: box-shadow .2s ease-out;
}

<div id="sch-brand-filter" contenteditable="false"></div>
```

Comment: F7 to turn Caret browsing on/off. Regards.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by that?